"Не могло" или "ни могло" в предложении
Как правильно: "не могло" или "ни могло" в предложении?

А за год какой только беды не могло случиться...


Спасибо за ответы и ссылки) Вот как раз у Розенталя и нашла для себя ответ, что "не" в моем случае вполне приемлемый вариант.

Как правильно: "не могло" или "ни могло" в предложении?
А за год какой только беды не могло случиться...
А почему не "ни"?
Возможно, у вас возникли трудности с написанием, потому что вы встречали подобное:
Кто ни проедет, всякий похвалит 

Куда ни оглянусь, повсюду рожь густая

Немного похоже на наш случай, но есть нюанс: "ни" пишется в придаточных предложениях для усиления утвердительного смысла. Ещё "ни" используется в устойчивых сочетаниях, для усиления отрицания, в качестве союза (повторяющаяся "ни"). Для подробного ознакомления изучите правила.

Можно  также посмотреть § 62, пункт 5.  Правописание частицы ни  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=82 Там рассматриваются такие пары.

Добавить комментарий
1
Спасибо за ответы и ссылки) Вот как раз у Розенталя и нашла для себя ответ, что "не" в моем случае вполне приемлемый вариант.
